# how do I save patched core after new upgrade

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I had to apply custom patch on Drupal 7 core and now I'm afraid that after rolling a new minor-upgrade over, it'll overwrite my changes.

Is there any way for me to preserve my changes even after upgrading to a new minor patch of core (in case that this patch haven't been applied to that version I'm upgrading to ), like creating a patched folder or something and make sure that my core stays operational ?

Thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would clone the site to some staging, update there and then compare old patched file with new one. Most likely the difference will be just the patch you applied and just copying patched file over will be enough. Other way some merging tool can help.

Comment: I guess that's only option. Thanks!